# Remove all entries except last 15 from database for each UserID

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database, sql-delete

I have a SQL server database and I would like to delete every row except the last 15, but, I need this to be per 'UserID'.

My database contains entries for a number of different users, where their ID is column 'UserID', so I want each user to have 15 entries in the database and the old ones to be removed.

What would the SQL be for this?

Here is an example effort from myself:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM SocialSenseTracking WHERE UserID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 15 UserID='$user' FROM SocialSenseTracking ORDER BY UserID DESC)";
```

Comment: So let me get this straight. Each user can have multiple entries in the database(lets say 100 for argument sakes). You want to delete the last 15 entries in the database for a particular user, so in our case, the other 85 based on either `id` or perhaps a timestamp, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I have a Timestamp column too, but just keeping the last 15 would suffice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a CTE and `row_number()` for this:

```
with todelete as (
      select sst.*, row_number() over (partition by UserId order by CreatedAt desc) as seqnum
      from SocialSenseTracking sst
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 15;
```

You don't specify the column used to determine the most recent records, so I just invented `CreatedAt`.

Comment: @Gordon..will this delete rows from the main table, 'SocialSenseTracking' in this case?

Comment: Thanks! This appears to work, but I'll run some tests to make sure.

I had to rename 'sst' to 'SocialSenseTracking' for it to work

Comment: Yes, the UPDATE needs the target table without an alias. This is sometimes annoying but rather usefull :-)